# how to make zoomable circle packing collapsible d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, circle-pack

I want to make zoomable circle packing collapsible like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/krancan/xqeh5cba/2/). My goal is limit number of nodes in circles. Nodes should be appearing when zooming deeper in cluster.

There are two different layouts, so i don't know how to join these examples. I have tried with visibility but there are problem with transforming when some nodes are hidden...

EDIT:
Here is new link: http://jsfiddle.net/krancan/xqeh5cba/6/ Collapsing behaviour is very strange.

```
[1]: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083
[2]: http://jsfiddle.net/krancan/xqeh5cba/2/
```

Comment: Could you post some code (a jsFiddle for example) with what you have for now and where exactly you're blocked?

Comment: I am still coding collapsible circle and there is strange behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/krancan/xqeh5cba/6/ What is wrong with transform? Why cannot increase after collapsing?

Comment: Why I have to click on root circle to refresh transform and other attributes after collapsing? What's wrong with collapsing and updating nodes?
http://jsfiddle.net/krancan/xqeh5cba/9/